# SVG polygon flickers on resize the parent div (it should preserve the actual shape)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, resize, polygon

**NOTE: We need go with Viewbox concept ONLY !**

---

I have a div(resize-div) in which I render SVG-polygon. I should be able to rearrange polygon points (by dragging and dropping them) or I can resize the resize-div.

**Scenario:1** : I should be able to re-arrange polygon points by dragging them anywhere and resize-div(parent-div) will be rearranged/resized to accommodate all points within it. **Which is working fine**.

**Scenario-2**: Once I'm done with rearranging the polygon points, If I try to **resize the resize-div(parent-div)**, the entire svg or some points flicker.  OR in other word, after re-arranging points, If I double tap the resize-div(parent-div), the entire shape flickers.

In scenario-2, I use

```
  arrVertexes = arrVertexes.map(item => {
        return [(xScale.invert(item[0])),  (yScale.invert(item[1])) ];
  });
```

but for scenario-1 I don't use **scale.invert**.

---

The expected behavior is it should not flicker. It should work as is.

**Been trying since last 2 weeks but no luck. Actual application is different. This is just a reproduction of what is happening in real-app**.

#### [DEMO - APP](https://codepen.io/micronyks/pen/LYZbQbG)

```
function resize(){

   arrVertexes = arrVertexes.map(item => {
        return [(xScale.invert(item[0])),  (yScale.invert(item[1])) ];
    });


    const eve = $('.resize-div').style; 
    eveWidth = $('.resize-div').width() - 2;
    eveHeight = $('.resize-div').height() - 2; 
   
    if (width !== eveWidth) {
      width = eveWidth; 
    }

    if (height !== eveHeight) { 
      height = eveHeight;
    }
    
    getScaledPoints();
    reload();
}
```

Not sure what is wrong. Tried to set preserveAspectRation(which I don't need) to none but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You code is a mess... I hardly understand what is going on there.

But one thing to mention. This code in `getScaledPoints` function:

```
return [Math.round(xScale(item[0])), Math.round(yScale(item[1]))];
```

Should be changed to:

```
return [xScale(item[0]), yScale(item[1])];
```

Do not make any rounding here! When you are working with "scaling", you should go into "real" numbers, not "integers". Example: [click](https://codepen.io/antoncodepen/pen/RwRKroz).

Comment: Thanks for your input but that can not be removed. If you do so, resize of parent will not work. I meant when you resize the outer div, inner shape will not be zoomed-in or zoomed-out. The requirement is like, you should be able to drag any point any where, according to it parent-div will be resized. And, when you resize parent-div manually, it will zoom-in or zoom-out or scale-up or down the polygon...

Comment: see I added `.gif` to explain you what I mean. As you can see I first drag bottom-right point (out side of parent-div). Parent-div gets resized (to accommodate all points within it). Then just double tap or resize the parent-div, points position gets flickered. The expected behavior is when I resize out-div, it should scale-up/down polygon as well. but it flickers.

Comment: I think I've found the solution. If you are working, pls wait for my input and don't continue.

Comment: Thanks a lot your input. It seems we have figure out the problem. However, thanks a ton for coming here and checking our complex code. Efforts are really appreciated !